# Using javascript to change the hue of an image

Tags: javascript, image

I have a background image on my site. On hover of some links (up to fifty links), i want to randomly change the hue of the background image.

Please how can i change the hue of an image?

Comment: do you need any further help with this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com) to [adjust the HSL](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/hsl/) of an image, but it won't work in all browsers, especially IE8 and lower.  The supported browsers list on the example page is a little out of date though and it should work with most browsers that support the `<canvas>` element.

If you need IE8 and lower support, you're out of luck because there's no filter available to make these kinds of adjustments.  You could try one of the other [BasicImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532972%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) filters, e.g. `GrayScale`, `Invert` or `XRay`.

Comment: Since some time Pixastic webpage does not respond to any request. But, you can still get it from GitHub: https://github.com/jseidelin/pixastic

Answer (score 0):

You would need a [FILTER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE and you can change the opacity in mozilla/webkit based browsers. Perhaps a [colored](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/color_value) div with an [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/opacity) over the image would work

[Here is a discussion](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=216892)

Is HTML5 an option?

Comment: pls will changing the opacity affect the hue?

Comment: @Ogugua Belonwu: he's suggesting placing a semi-transparent colored div over the image ..

Comment: Or the opacity of the div that has the image as background image

Comment: But what if the image itself contains opacity? What then?

Comment: This answer is 6 years old. I assume stuff has changed since